How can I programatically get which process is holding an open handle to my microphone?
I am writing a program that should do detection of camera/microphone use.
By leveraging the following registry key, I managed to get notified when a program is using my microphone:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\microphone
Thus, I could retrieve the ImagePath of the process.
However, for web browsers like chrome.exe, it has a lot of processes running under the same name. I do not want to kill all of them, I want to kill the specific one that has the microphone handle open.
After some research, I managed to find how to do this manually for the camera, but it is not working for the microphone as detailed in this question: How can I find out which processes on my computer are accessing the microphone?
Another problem is, even though the registry event is telling me directly that chrome.exe is using the camera, by researching the camera handle in Process Explorer, the handle is actually held by svchost.exe.
How can I make any relation between the calling chrome.exe and the svchost.exe that is opening the camera? Is it possible?

If you kill one Chrome process, they all die together, so don't worry too much about that.

Microsoft Sysinternals will help you tremendously, in particular the suite of process utilities.  I second what MSalters said about killing random processes — that won't end well.  Good luck!

@Eljay Thank you, I tried Process explorer already  to find the handle of the microphone by searching with its PDO but does not work I don't know why

@anitarazafi: That's because Windows nowadays allows multiple applications to share a microphone, which wouldn't work if one of them had it exclusively open.

In Windows, apps can open the microphone simultaneously or shared. "Exclusively"  open is not forcing.
If you use waveInOpen to open it, it's not opened exclusively.
If you use  IAudioCaptureClient
to open it, it may be opened exclusively or in shared mode.
Apps may also open audio with ASIO or another hardware-based way, so even if opened exclusively with one API, it may be opened with another api or get denied for opening for any reason.
Either way, you don't know and you shouldn't search. Even if you would try to create an audio driver, the opener may just pick the driver it wants.

The reason you see svchost is because svchost has that microphone open. That's the host process for Windows services, including the audio service. Kill it, and your PC will most likely crash.
This seems related to another assumption in your question: "the" microphone. What if you have two? The linked question sidesteps that by checking a specific webcam, but your registry approach doesn't. And of course, there is the flip side of that assumption: "the" application. There can be multiple applications sharing the same microphone nowadays.
On the whole, this gives me the impression that your understanding of Windows is insufficient. Killing random processes based on a misunderstanding of how Windows work sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Thank you for the reply,
Indeed, there is only one microphone attached to the system at the moment of testing.
The registry keys event actually works fine for both the webcam and microphone devices, it gives me notification when any process has started using one of them.
the whole picture is that after sending the notification to the user which process has started using the webcam/microphone, the user can choose between block or allow
the only way I found to implement "block" was to kill the process
The issue araise when there are multiple tabs of chrome (and I want to kill only one)

@anitarazafi: It might be useful to get a second USB microphone, so you can understand how Windows handles that. Just because you have only one microphone  now doesn't mean that Windows is restricted to one microphone. Your software shouldn't crash itself or the whole PC when a user has two microphones. That's not even uncommon: use a USB headset with a microphone on a laptop with a built-in microhone.

As for "blocking the microphone", that's exactly the point of that CapabilityAccessManager whose registry key you found. You appear to be duplicating core Windows functionality, and that too is a recipe for problems.
